# Java's System.getRuntime().exec not behaving as if the shell user called it

Tags: java, sendmail, runtime.exec

I am running a java application from the console on an HP-UX machine. In it, I generate some reports, zip them, and then email them. Everything is working, except the email.

I am using the mail binary to send mail from the command line. Since it's HP-UX, it's a bit different than the standard GNU sendmail.

This is the code I'm using to send the mail:

```
    public static void EmailReports(String[] recipients, String reportArchive, String subject){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String today = dateFormat.format(new Date());

        File tempEmailFile;
        BufferedWriter emailWriter;
        try {
            tempEmailFile = File.createTempFile("report_email_" + today, "msg");
            emailWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempEmailFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not create temporary file.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            emailWriter.write("SUBJECT: " + subject + "\n");
            emailWriter.write("FROM: " + FROM + "\n");
            emailWriter.write(BODY + "\n"); 
            emailWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not write to temporary file.");
        }

        //read the archive in
        try {
            FileInputStream archiveIS = new FileInputStream(new File(reportArchive));
            OutputStream archiveEncoder = MimeUtility.encode(new FileOutputStream(tempEmailFile, true), "uuencode", Zipper.getArchiveName(reportArchive));

            //read archive
            byte[] buffer = new byte[archiveIS.available()];    //these should never be more than a megabyte or two, so storing it in memory is no big deal.
            archiveIS.read(buffer);

            //encode archive
            archiveEncoder.write(buffer);

            //close both
            archiveIS.close();
            archiveEncoder.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not find archive to email.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not encode archive.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not encode archive.");
        }
        System.out.println("Sending '" + subject + "' email.");     

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath());

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while(p.getErrorStream().available() > 0){
                buffer.append((char) p.getErrorStream().read());
            }

            System.out.println("STDERR: " + buffer.toString());

            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while(p.getInputStream().available() > 0){
                buffer.append((char) p.getInputStream().read());
            }

            System.out.println("STDOUT: " + buffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not get access to the shell.");
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, and it sends the email, I get a blank email, no subject, no body, no attachment, and it's from the user@hostname from the HP-UX box instead of from the email specified in `FROM`.

However, when I run the same line that it runs (see the command printed out after I call exec), I get the correct email, from the correct user, with a subject, body, and attachment.

STDOUT and STDERR are both empty. It's almost as if I'm sending mail a blank file, but when I print the file before I call the exec, it's there.

What's going on here?

Edit: Attempts made:

Using Ksh:

```
    try {
        String cmd = "mail me@example.com.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath();            
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/usr/bin/ksh", cmd});

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not get access to the shell.");
    }
```

Using STDIN:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath());

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mail me@example.com ");

        FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(tempEmailFile);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[inFile.available()];
        inFile.read(byteBuffer);
        p.getOutputStream().write(byteBuffer);

        inFile.close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(p.getErrorStream().available() > 0){
            buffer.append((char) p.getErrorStream().read());
        }

        System.out.println("STDERR: " + buffer.toString());

        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(p.getInputStream().available() > 0){
            buffer.append((char) p.getInputStream().read());
        }

        System.out.println("STDOUT: " + buffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to send email. Could not get access to the shell.");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is the redirection. That's normally handled by the shell - and there's no shell here.

*Either* you need to execute the process normally and then get the process's standard input stream and write to it from Java, *or* (probably simpler) run `/bin/sh` (or whatever) to get the shell to do the redirection.

Comment: Neither of those worked. Didn't even get the blank email. KSH is the shell in use.

Comment: @Malfist: Well I expect both of them will work if done correctly. Please edit your post with an example of how you tried using the shell.

Comment: @Malfist: Well for a start, you're using `available()` and assuming the whole file is going to be read in one go - always a bad idea. For the ksh example, you may well need to pass in `-c` to say that the rest of it is the command.

Comment: what would cause available not to return the whole file? They files are typically less than 5 megabytes so it's safe to read the whole thing into memory.

Comment: @Malfist: It's safe to read the whole thing into memory, but you should *never* assume that a single call to `read()` will read the whole stream, or that `available()` will tell you the total length of the stream. (I'd make an exception for `ByteArrayInputStream`, but avoid `available()` there anyway.) Imagine a file is on a network file share, for example - I can well imagine it not returning everything in one go then. It's simply bad practice to read a file this way - there are perfectly reliable ways of doing it by looping.

Answer (score 2):

Try exec'ing `{ "ksh", "-c", "mail me@example.com < " + etc }`. The `-c` option tells the shell specifically to parse the next argument as a shell command with possible redirection and so on. Without the `-c`, ksh follows a heuristic to decide what to do with its command line, and it may not be running the command in the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Split into two lines, just to get better readability:

```
        String cmd = "mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath () ;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (cmd);
```

This will look for a program named `"mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath ()`. It will not do redirection - for that to do you have to read the output of that process yourself.

Furtermore it will not lookup the path, so you might have to specify the whole path /usr/bin/mail or whatever it is.

And you have to split command and parameters; use an Array of String instead: ("/path/to/prg", "param1", "param2", "foo=bar");

You can use redirection, if you call as program a script, like

```
String cmd = "/usr/bin/mail me@example.com < " + tempEmailFile.getAbsolutePath () ;
String cmdarr = new String [] {"/bin/bash", "-c", cmd}; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (cmdarr);
```

It is shorter than invoking file redirection from Java yourself, more simple but you lose the ability to react sensible on different errors.

Comment: HP-UX uses ksh, will I need to add additional parameters?

Comment: @Malfist: "didn't work" is a bit vague. I forgot to add an absolute path to mail again. Updating... - might need "-c" to pass a command as String, at least for bash. Consult the ksh-manual how to invoke the ksh binary with a script as string.