# Java exec() mysqldump error: Couldn't find table ">"

Tags: java, exec, mysql

I'm executing mysqldump command from a Java class but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

This is the code I'm using:

```
        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -pmypassword valo > /etc/valbu.sql");
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if(processComplete == 0){
            System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
        } else {
            InputStream stderr = runtimeProcess.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("<ERROR>");
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("</ERROR>");
            System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
        }
```

It looks like he doesn't understand that `>` isn't a table but a command to dump.

Comment: Don't pass credentials as command line parameters! They might be visible for other users on the host (through `ps -o args`). Instead, pass them as environment variables, or through stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because `Runtime.exec()` will not invoke a shell, and `>` is a shell redirection.

So, either use an array like `{ "/bin/bash", "-c", "thescripthere" }`, (not recommended) or use, say, a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the array command works fine. Since it is not reccomended, i'd like to get into the processbuilder. I'll have some research about it thanks a lot!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can some explain why is this approach not recommended ?

Answer (score 3):

Common problem - You can't execute a statement with a pipe or a redirection. They can only be executed by the shell.

**Further further reading**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693833/105224

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `result-file` option in the mysqldump command instead of the redirection operator `>`:

`mysqldump -uroot -pmypassword valo --result-file=/etc/valbu.sql`

Comment: BOOM! Fast, effective relief

Comment: Thanks, Man @CfSimplicity ! I was looking for this for hours; worked like charm!!